# Assigning VF component attribute to a List controller class variable

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, controller, list

I have a VF page using a standard controller, a component, and a custom controller for the component.  I am trying to pass a list of sObjects from the standard controller to the component's custom controller.  Currently, I have it set up as follows:

In VF page:

```
...   
 <c:ProjectSummaryComponent project="{!Project__c}" summaries="{!Project__c.Project_Summaries__r}" />
...
```

In VF component:

```
   <apex:component controller="ProjectSummaryController">
       <apex:attribute name="project" type="Project__c" required="true" description="The Project__c record" />
       <apex:attribute name="summaries" type="Project_Summary__c[]" assignTo="{!projectSummaries}" required="true" description="The list of Project Summaries." />
    ...
```

In controller:

```
public with sharing class ProjectSummaryController {
    public Project_Summary__c[] projectSummaries {get; set;}
...
```

I get no build errors from this code, but when viewing the page, I get this Visualforce error message:

```
Cannot convert the value of '{!projectSummaries}' to the expected type.
```

I'm not sure what is wrong here, since the type is specified to be Project_Summary__c[] in both the component and the controller.  From the component, I can actually display the list of Project_Summary__c records that were passed from the main page.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Square brackets are only supported in some contexts. Try using List<Project_Summary__c> instead.

Comment: I've actually tried using List<Project_Summary__c>.  If I substitute Project_Summary__c[] with List<Project_Summary__c> in the VF component, I get a build error stating List<Project_Summary__c> is an unsupported type.  Substituting the [] with List in the controller doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 3):

I confirmed this behavior in my own test and was able to work around it as follows:

**VF component:**

```
<c:ProjectSummaryComponent project="{!Project__c}" summaries="{!projectSummaries}" />
```

...

**VF controller:**

```
private Project__c  getProjWSummaries (){
                            return [select id, name, 
                                       (select id, name from Project_Summaries__r) 
                                     from Project__c where id = :this.project__c.id][0];}
public List<Project_Summary__c> projectSummaries {
   get {return getProjWSummaries().project_summaries__r;} private set; }
```

**VF component**: no change

The problem has something to do with the relationship Project_Summaries__r if provided directly as you did in the OP when assigned to the component's controller.  What exactly I do not know. As you can see from the code above, simply fetching the relationship in a property of List type works fine.