# Child Relationship use in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, relationships, related-list, childrelationship

In a visualforce page I can get a list of child records directly (without any query) using the child relationship name like `{!ParentObject__c.Child_Relationship_name__r}` and this list is of the type of the Child Object.

```
<apex:page standardController="ParentObject__c">
     <apex:repeat value="{!ParentObject__c.Child_Relationship_name__r}" var="child">
         {!child.Name}//Or any field
     </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

### Problem

This brings me to my problem, when I have a visualforce component that has an attribute of type `ChildObject__c[]` that I assign to a property in the component's controller of the same type I get the error

> Cannot convert the value of '{!childList}' to the expected type.

But if instead of using the relationship list I construct a list of ChildObject__c (i.e. `List<ChildObject__c>`) with a query, it works as expected and the list gets displayed.

### Code

Component_Ctrl.cls

```
public with sharing class Component_Ctrl {
    public List<ChildObject__c> childList {get;set;}
}
```

Comp.component

```
<apex:component controller="Component_Ctrl">
    <apex:attribute name="children" type="ChildObject__c[]" description="A list of child objects for the component assignTo="{!childList}" required="true"/>
    <apex:repeat value="{!childList}" var="child">
         {!child.Name}//Or any field
     </apex:repeat>
</apex:component>
```

Visualforce.page

```
<apex:page standardController="ParentObject__c">
     <c:Comp children="{!ParentObject__c.Child_Relationship_name__r}"/><!--Here I get the error-->
     <!--<c:Comp children="{!children}"/>--><!--This one works when children is constructed from a query-->
</apex:page>
```

I already have the query workaround implemented, but I want to understand why the first option fails, I want to avoid that extra query.

Comment: Seems to be a bug that has yet to be solved. Most likely because SF does not let us submit bugs unless we pay for premier support: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/57214/assigning-vf-component-attribute-to-a-list-controller-class-variable

Comment: Yes @Eric, it looks like a bug, I missed that question.